# How Can I Make Static Variable Working In Publish Mode In iis7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In My Project As Asp.net Mvc 4.5 I Make static List Of String. In This List Add String Variable this list work in debug mode when run Visual studio but when make publish not work 
this is my code

what i see when make publish and open this view from different browser not get data inserted from other browser which open this view

ex> when open in chrom and set str variable to 1 then 2 
i will see in chrom 1 then 2

when get url and reopen in different browser like firefox cant see 1 , 2 
this is what i needed to see

```
public static class GetOnLineUser
    {
        public static List<string> NewList;
        public static string StaticList(string str)
        {
            if(NewList==null)
                NewList = new List<string>();
            var sp = new StringBuilder();
            if (!NewList.Contains(str) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                NewList.Add(str);
            if (NewList != null && NewList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var st in NewList)
                {
                    sp.Append(st);
                    sp.Append("<br/>");
                }
            }
            return sp.ToString();
        }
    }


public class TestStController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /TestSt/
        public string Index(string str)
        {
            return GetOnLineUser.StaticList(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but when make publish not work" doesn't tell us *anything* about what you're seeing. Your code certainly isn't thread-safe, for one thing, and it's unclear what you want it to accomplish... but what are you observing? What's the actual *problem* here?

Comment: what i see when make publish and open this view from different browser not get data inserted from other browser which open this view

ex> when open in chrom and set str variable to 1 then 2 i will see in chrom 1 then 2

when get url and reopen in different browser like firefox cant see 1 , 2 this is what i needed to see

Comment: So what *do* you see in Firefox? (You might want to consider using `string.Join`, by the way... and think about thread safety...)

Comment: what do you main about thread safety. all what i needed like stored variable as list<string> add value on it and get all in different browser for all logon user

Comment: I mean that if your method gets called from multiple threads at the same time, that could easily cause problems in various different ways.

Comment: no i don't use any thread in my application. what i needed when any user logon from any browser add name or any string in this static list and any one logon can see all data in this list

Comment: You're writing a web application. It's automatically multithreaded.

Comment: Static variables + web application = FAIL. Plain and simple. Just don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

This Issue Because Configuration in iis Application Pool For This Site In Publish Mode On Server. 
To Fix It Open Iis And Select Application Pools For This Site. Then Open Advanced Settings For This Application Pool. And Select [ Process Model ] From Display Panel And Set [ User Profile ] = False 
This Configuration Make Any Static Variable Worked To Me

Comment: It really isn't clear from the question or the answer you posted what the actual issue was in the first place, or what the fix actually accomplished.  It is also very hard to read this answer, due to your use of capitalization for every word.